# GRAPH_TRAVERSAL_TREE ignores filterVertices, GRAPH_TRAVERSAL doesn't

Tags: arangodb

I'm trying to prune a traversal.  When I use the AQL GRAPH_TRAVERSAL function it works as expected.  However, changing the GRAPH_TRAVERSAL function with GRAPH_TRAVERSAL_TREE expands the whole tree past the filterVertices examples.

Is there something I need to change on my end when moving from GRAPH_TRAVERSAL to GRAPH_TRAVERSAL_TREE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While trying to reproduce your question I went into a similar pitfall: I forgot one parameter to the `GRAPH_TRAVERSAL_TREE()` - function, which then would return more results than expected. When the number of arguments is correct, we can compare a [traversal over the city graph](https://docs.arangodb.com/2.8/Graphs/index.html#the-city-graph):

Unfiltered we will also see `Paris` and the nodes behind it in the result set:

```
FOR e IN GRAPH_TRAVERSAL_TREE('routeplanner',
  'germanCity/Hamburg',
  'outbound',
  'connection') RETURN e"
```

If we filter for `isCapital == false`, these nodes will be missing:

```
FOR e IN GRAPH_TRAVERSAL_TREE('routeplanner', 
  'germanCity/Hamburg',
  'outbound',
  'connection',
  {filterVertices: [{isCapital: false }]}) RETURN e
```

Please note the parameter with the `'connection'` string, which specifies how to name the sub attribute in the result. If you forget it, the options object will take its place, and you will see key names like `'[object Object]'` in the result plus the filtering not working.

Comment: FOR v IN GRAPH_TRAVERSAL('gdp2_graph',[{_id:'pmsite/527362551703'}],'outbound',{strategy:'depthfirst',edgeCollectionRestriction:'pm_child',vertexFilterMethod:['prune','exclude'],filterVertices:[{kind:'site'},{kind:'path_1'},{kind:'path_2'},{kind:'project'}]}) RETURN v

This works.  However, I wanted to get the parent<->child relationships so I changed it to GRAPH_TRAVERSAL_TREE which gave me the tree but didn't stop at the same points where GRAPH_TRAVERSAL did.

I have gotten an alternative form of FOR <start>..<end> IN to give me what I need but I just wanted to alert you to this anomaly.

Comment: As stated in the last paragraph, you need to add the `connectName` parameter before the object with the Pattern matching. But for shure the pattern matching traversal is to be prefered above `GRAPH_TRAVERSAL(_TREE)`